# exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No reply topic header and no default reply topic is can be determined

Tags: spring-batch, spring-integration

I am trying to implement remote partitioning using Kafka as middle wear and getting exceptions. Just to start on this topic, started working only on master and facing problems once the master is done will work on worker side code.

Below is the stack trace of the exception

```
2020-10-16 00:27:48.640  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka version: 2.5.0
2020-10-16 00:27:48.641  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka commitId: 66563e712b0b9f84
2020-10-16 00:27:48.641  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.a.kafka.common.utils.AppInfoParser     : Kafka startTimeMs: 1602788268633
2020-10-16 00:27:48.652  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.a.k.clients.consumer.KafkaConsumer     : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testPokRequestsorab-1, groupId=testPokRequestsorab] Subscribed to topic(s): reply
2020-10-16 00:27:48.657  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.s.c.ThreadPoolTaskScheduler          : Initializing ExecutorService
2020-10-16 00:27:48.670  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : Adding {kafka:outbound-gateway} as a subscriber to the 'requests' channel
2020-10-16 00:27:48.671  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : Channel 'application-1.requests' has 1 subscriber(s).
2020-10-16 00:27:48.671  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.i.endpoint.EventDrivenConsumer       : started bean 'outboundGateFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'io.spring.batch.configuration.MasterActualConf'; from source: 'bean method outboundGateFlow'
2020-10-16 00:27:48.751  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
2020-10-16 00:27:49.940  INFO 13716 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Triggering deferred initialization of Spring Data repositories…
2020-10-16 00:27:49.941  INFO 13716 --- [           main] DeferredRepositoryInitializationListener : Spring Data repositories initialized!
2020-10-16 00:27:49.972  INFO 13716 --- [           main] i.s.b.configuration.MasterActualConf     : Started MasterActualConf in 29.713 seconds (JVM running for 32.146)
2020-10-16 00:27:49.976  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.b.JobLauncherApplicationRunner   : Running default command line with: []
************************Inside  batchConfigurer    ****************
2020-10-16 00:27:50.017  INFO 13716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Starting...
2020-10-16 00:27:50.017  WARN 13716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.util.DriverDataSource  : Registered driver with driverClassName=org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver was not found, trying direct instantiation.
2020-10-16 00:27:50.018  INFO 13716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.pool.PoolBase          : HikariPool-2 - Driver does not support get/set network timeout for connections. (feature not supported)
2020-10-16 00:27:50.019  INFO 13716 --- [           main] com.zaxxer.hikari.HikariDataSource       : HikariPool-2 - Start completed.
2020-10-16 00:27:50.290  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=remotePartitioningJobMy]] launched with the following parameters: [{run.id=44}]
2020-10-16 00:27:50.408  WARN 13716 --- [           main] o.s.c.t.b.l.TaskBatchExecutionListener   : This job was executed outside the scope of a task but still used the task listener.
2020-10-16 00:27:50.426  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler     : Executing step: [masterStep]
2020-10-16 00:27:50.473 DEBUG 13716 --- [           main] o.s.integration.channel.DirectChannel    : preSend on channel 'bean 'requests'; defined in: 'io.spring.batch.configuration.MasterActualConf'; from source: 'org.springframework.core.type.StandardMethodMetadata@4263b080'', message: GenericMessage [payload=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=64, stepExecutionId=94, stepName=workerStep], headers={sequenceNumber=0, replyChannel=bean 'org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow#0.channel#0', correlationId=64:workerStep, id=8b7b56e5-a1a5-cc70-9ee0-ce0d1c077f34, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1602788270472}]
2020-10-16 00:27:50.474 DEBUG 13716 --- [           main] o.s.i.k.o.KafkaProducerMessageHandler    : bean 'outboundGateFlow.kafka:outbound-gateway#0' for component 'outboundGateFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'io.spring.batch.configuration.MasterActualConf'; from source: 'bean method outboundGateFlow' received message: GenericMessage [payload=StepExecutionRequest: [jobExecutionId=64, stepExecutionId=94, stepName=workerStep], headers={sequenceNumber=0, replyChannel=bean 'org.springframework.integration.dsl.StandardIntegrationFlow#0.channel#0', correlationId=64:workerStep, id=8b7b56e5-a1a5-cc70-9ee0-ce0d1c077f34, sequenceSize=1, timestamp=1602788270472}]
2020-10-16 00:27:50.491 ERROR 13716 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Encountered an error executing step masterStep in job remotePartitioningJobMy

org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'outboundGateFlow.kafka:outbound-gateway#0' for component 'outboundGateFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'io.spring.batch.configuration.MasterActualConf'; from source: 'bean method outboundGateFlow']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: No reply topic header and no default reply topic is can be determined
    at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:192)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:79)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:99)
    at org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.MessageChannelPartitionHandler.handle(MessageChannelPartitionHandler.java:228)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.partition.support.PartitionStep.doExecute(PartitionStep.java:106)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.step.AbstractStep.execute(AbstractStep.java:208)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleStepHandler.handleStep(SimpleStepHandler.java:148)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.handleStep(AbstractJob.java:410)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.SimpleJob.doExecute(SimpleJob.java:136)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.job.AbstractJob.execute(AbstractJob.java:319)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher$1.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:147)
    at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.SimpleJobLauncher.run(SimpleJobLauncher.java:140)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
    at org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.SimpleBatchConfiguration$PassthruAdvice.invoke(SimpleBatchConfiguration.java:127)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
    at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:212)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy98.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.execute(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:199)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.executeLocalJobs(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:173)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.launchJobFromProperties(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:160)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:155)
    at org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.batch.JobLauncherApplicationRunner.run(JobLauncherApplicationRunner.java:150)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunner(SpringApplication.java:786)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.callRunners(SpringApplication.java:776)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:322)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1237)
    at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1226)
    at io.spring.batch.configuration.MasterActualConf.main(MasterActualConf.java:188)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: No reply topic header and no default reply topic is can be determined
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.getReplyTopic(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:487)
    at org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(KafkaProducerMessageHandler.java:398)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:134)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)
    ... 43 common frames omitted

2020-10-16 00:27:50.513  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.batch.core.step.AbstractStep         : Step: [masterStep] executed in 86ms
2020-10-16 00:27:50.526  INFO 13716 --- [           main] o.s.b.c.l.support.SimpleJobLauncher      : Job: [SimpleJob: [name=remotePartitioningJobMy]] completed with the following parameters: [{run.id=44}] and the following status: [FAILED] in 120ms
2020-10-16 00:27:50.818  INFO 13716 --- [lyContainer-C-1] org.apache.kafka.clients.Metadata        : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testPokRequestsorab-1, groupId=testPokRequestsorab] Cluster ID: ZBfa0qdHQIaIzmOVv1fiFg
2020-10-16 00:27:50.824  INFO 13716 --- [lyContainer-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testPokRequestsorab-1, groupId=testPokRequestsorab] Discovered group coordinator cdh5161-e2e-test-7.eaas.amdocs.com:9092 (id: 2147483570 rack: null)
2020-10-16 00:27:50.841  INFO 13716 --- [lyContainer-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testPokRequestsorab-1, groupId=testPokRequestsorab] (Re-)joining group
2020-10-16 00:27:54.824  INFO 13716 --- [lyContainer-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testPokRequestsorab-1, groupId=testPokRequestsorab] Finished assignment for group at generation 45: {consumer-testPokRequestsorab-1-55bf445d-709f-423f-9e29-c42662589397=Assignment(partitions=[reply-0])}
2020-10-16 00:27:55.060  INFO 13716 --- [lyContainer-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.AbstractCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testPokRequestsorab-1, groupId=testPokRequestsorab] Successfully joined group with generation 45
2020-10-16 00:27:55.072  INFO 13716 --- [lyContainer-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testPokRequestsorab-1, groupId=testPokRequestsorab] Adding newly assigned partitions: reply-0
2020-10-16 00:27:55.422  INFO 13716 --- [lyContainer-C-1] o.s.k.l.KafkaMessageListenerContainer    : testPokRequestsorab: partitions assigned: [reply-0]
2020-10-16 00:27:55.672  INFO 13716 --- [lyContainer-C-1] o.a.k.c.c.internals.ConsumerCoordinator  : [Consumer clientId=consumer-testPokRequestsorab-1, groupId=testPokRequestsorab] Setting offset for partition reply-0 to the committed offset FetchPosition{offset=0, offsetEpoch=Optional.empty, currentLeader=LeaderAndEpoch{leader=Optional[cdh5161-e2e-test-1.eaas.amdocs.com:9092 (id: 63 rack: null)], epoch=absent}}

Process finished with exit code -1
```

In my case, I had to use two databases, one for repository and one as source and for this i had impemented BatchConfigurer , job repository and one data source creation in class .

Below is the code i am using

Configuration and main class

```
package io.spring.batch.configuration;

import io.spring.batch.domain.ColumnRangePartitioner;
import org.apache.kafka.clients.producer.ProducerRecord;
import org.apache.kafka.common.header.internals.RecordHeader;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Job;
import org.springframework.batch.core.Step;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.BatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.DefaultBatchConfigurer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.EnableBatchProcessing;
import org.springframework.batch.core.configuration.annotation.JobBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.core.launch.support.RunIdIncrementer;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.JobRepository;
import org.springframework.batch.core.repository.support.JobRepositoryFactoryBean;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.config.annotation.EnableBatchIntegration;
import org.springframework.batch.integration.partition.RemotePartitioningMasterStepBuilderFactory;
import org.springframework.batch.support.transaction.ResourcelessTransactionManager;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.jdbc.DataSourceBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ImportResource;
import org.springframework.integration.annotation.ServiceActivator;
import org.springframework.integration.channel.DirectChannel;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlow;
import org.springframework.integration.dsl.IntegrationFlows;
import org.springframework.integration.kafka.dsl.Kafka;
import org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.integration.kafka.outbound.KafkaProducerMessageHandler;
import org.springframework.kafka.config.ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ConsumerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.KafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.core.ProducerFactory;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.ContainerProperties;
import org.springframework.kafka.listener.KafkaMessageListenerContainer;
import org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.ReplyingKafkaTemplate;
import org.springframework.kafka.requestreply.RequestReplyFuture;
import org.springframework.kafka.support.KafkaHeaders;
import javax.sql.DataSource;



@SpringBootApplication
@EnableBatchProcessing
@EnableBatchIntegration
@ImportResource("context.xml")
public class MasterActualConf {


    private final JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory;

    private final RemotePartitioningMasterStepBuilderFactory masterStepBuilderFactory;

    private static final int GRID_SIZE = 4;

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel replies() {
        return new DirectChannel();
    }

    @Bean
    public DirectChannel requests() {return new DirectChannel(); }

    @Autowired
    private KafkaTemplate<String, String> kafkaTemplate;

    @Bean
    public Step masterStep() {
        System.out.println("*******************  inside  masterStep **************************");
        return this.masterStepBuilderFactory.get("masterStep")
                .partitioner("workerStep", new ColumnRangePartitioner())
                .gridSize(GRID_SIZE)
                .outputChannel(requests())
                .inputChannel(replies())
                .build();
    }

    @Bean
    public Job remotePartitioningJob() {
        System.out.println("*******************  inside  remotePartitioningJob **************************");
        return this.jobBuilderFactory.get("remotePartitioningJobMy")
                .incrementer(new RunIdIncrementer())
                .start(masterStep())
                .build();
    }

    protected JobRepository createMyJobRepository() throws Exception {
        JobRepositoryFactoryBean factory = new JobRepositoryFactoryBean();
        factory.setTransactionManager(new ResourcelessTransactionManager());
        factory.setDataSource(createDataSourceForRepository());
        factory.setDatabaseType("HSQL");
        return factory.getObject();
    }


    public DataSource createDataSourceForRepository() {
        return DataSourceBuilder.create()
                .url("jdbc:hsqldb:file:src/main/resources/hsqldb/batchcore.db;shutdown=true;")
                .driverClassName("org.hsqldb.jdbcDriver")
                .username("sa")
                .password("")
                .build();
    }


    @Bean
    public BatchConfigurer batchConfigurer() {
        return new DefaultBatchConfigurer(createDataSourceForRepository()) {
            @Override
            public JobRepository getJobRepository() {
                JobRepository jobRepository = null;
                try {
                    jobRepository = createMyJobRepository();

                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                System.out.println("************************Inside  batchConfigurer    ****************");
                return jobRepository;
            }
        };
    }


    @Bean
    public KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> replyContainer(ConsumerFactory<String, String> cf) {
        ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties("reply");
        System.out.println("************************** replyContainer  *****************************");
        return new KafkaMessageListenerContainer<>(cf, containerProperties);
    }


    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> replyingTemplate(ProducerFactory<String, String> producerFactory,KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer) {
        System.out.println("**************************replyingTemplate Templet  *****************************");
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(producerFactory, repliesContainer);
    }


    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow outboundGateFlow( ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String , String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic("reply");
        return IntegrationFlows.from(requests())
                .handle(Kafka.outboundGateway(kafkaTemplate).topic("requests").partitionId(0))
                .channel("requests")
                .get();
    }


      /*
    @ServiceActivator(inputChannel = "requests", outputChannel = "reply")
    public KafkaProducerMessageHandler<String, String> outGateway(ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
        ProducerRecord<String, String> record = new ProducerRecord<>("kRequests", "foo");
        record.headers().add(new RecordHeader(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, "kReplies".getBytes()));
        RequestReplyFuture<String, String, String> replyFuture = kafkaTemplate.sendAndReceive(record);
        System.out.println("****************inside gateway **************************");
        //SendResult<String, String> sendResult = replyFuture.getSendFuture().get();
        //System.out.println("Sent ok: " + sendResult.getRecordMetadata());
        //ConsumerRecord<String, String> consumerRecord = replyFuture.get();
        //System.out.println("Return value: " + consumerRecord.value());
        return new KafkaProducerMessageHandler<>(kafkaTemplate);
    }

 */
    @Bean
    public ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer(ConcurrentKafkaListenerContainerFactory<String, String> containerFactory) {
        ConcurrentMessageListenerContainer<String, String> repliesContainer = containerFactory.createContainer("reply");
        repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().setGroupId("repliesGroup");
        System.out.println("**************** reply topic ki khoj " + repliesContainer.getContainerProperties().getTopics()[0] + "*****************************");
        repliesContainer.setAutoStartup(false);
        return repliesContainer;
    }

    @Bean
    public ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String, String, String> kafkaTemplate(
            ProducerFactory<String, String> pf, KafkaMessageListenerContainer<String, String> replyContainer) {
        return new ReplyingKafkaTemplate<>(pf, replyContainer);
    }

    public MasterActualConf(JobBuilderFactory jobBuilderFactory, RemotePartitioningMasterStepBuilderFactory masterStepBuilderFactory) {
        this.jobBuilderFactory = jobBuilderFactory;
        this.masterStepBuilderFactory = masterStepBuilderFactory;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(MasterActualConf.class, args);
    }

}
```

Basic partitioner class

```
import java.util.Map;

public class BasicPartitioner extends SimplePartitioner {

    private static final String PARTITION_KEY = "partition";

    @Override
    public Map<String, ExecutionContext> partition(int gridSize) {
        Map<String, ExecutionContext> partitions = super.partition(gridSize);
        int i = 0;
        for (ExecutionContext context : partitions.values()) {
            context.put(PARTITION_KEY, PARTITION_KEY + (i++));
        }
        System.out.println("#########################Inside Basic Partitioner  ##################   ");
        return partitions;
    }

}
```

pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
         xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
         xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.3.1.RELEASE</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>


    <groupId>RemotePartitioningTest</groupId>
    <artifactId>RemotePartitioningTest</artifactId>
    <version>1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>

    <properties>
        <java.version>1.8</java.version>
        <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR6</spring-cloud.version>
    </properties>

    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.cloud.stream.app/spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-local -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud.stream.app</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-stream-sink-task-launcher-local</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.6.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-task-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-amqp</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-binder-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.kafka</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-kafka-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-file</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-stream -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-stream</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-zookeeper</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework.integration/spring-integration-amqp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.integration</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-integration-amqp</artifactId>
            <version>5.3.2.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-stream-test-support</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-batch</artifactId>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-task</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hsqldb</groupId>
            <artifactId>hsqldb</artifactId>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <version>5.0.4</version>
        </dependency>

        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/commons-dbcp/commons-dbcp -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-dbcp</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-dbcp</artifactId>
            <version>1.2.2</version>
        </dependency>


        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.batch</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-batch-integration</artifactId>
        </dependency>


    </dependencies>

    <dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>
        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>

    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Answer (score 1):

The outbound gateway can only infer the reply topic if the reply container is assigned to exactly one partition. You can assign it manually:

```
ContainerProperties containerProperties = new ContainerProperties(
    new TopicPartitionOffset("reply", 0));
```

or you need to add a header enricher...

```java
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow outboundGateFlow( ReplyingKafkaTemplate<String , String, String> kafkaTemplate) {
    kafkaTemplate.setDefaultTopic("reply");
    return IntegrationFlows.from(requests())
            .enrichHeaders(h -> h.header(KafkaHeaders.REPLY_TOPIC, "reply"))
            .handle(Kafka.outboundGateway(kafkaTemplate).topic("requests").partitionId(0))
            .channel("requests")
            .get();

}
```

Comment: Fixed the syntax.

Comment: Thanks, Gary. As always your suggestion worked but now getting new issues. Now I am getting serialization exception of serialization.

I have posted my query in the new question  

 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64416510/spring-batch-remote-partitioning-serialization-issue-for-stepexecution-handler